# What is the difference between a QScrollEvent and a QWheelEvent?

Tags: qt, scroll

What is the difference between a QScrollEvent and a QWheelEvent? I know QWheelEvent detects scrolls, but what is QScrollEvent useful for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum) provides this:

- QScrollEvent: The scroll event is sent to indicate that the receiver should be scrolled.
- QWheelEvent: Indicates the mouse wheel has rolled.

Spinning the mouse wheel does not need to initiate a scrolling behavior. You can make it zoom in or whatever you want.

And likewise, a scroll event does not need to come from a mouse wheel. It could come from dragging the scrollbar or anything else.

So the events do not mean the same thing.